# Z-index issue image not hiding

Tags: html, css, z-index

If you check the site that i am currently working on www.darecreations.suprex.me I was able to get one of the angle laptops on the left side to hide behind the center mac-pro but I am having problems hiding the other mac image behind the center mac like to did not the left side and z-index was not working is there any way to solve this issue thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post the relevant code in your actual question, or it will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

If you explicitly set `position: relative` on the middle and right laptops the `z-index` will work. The reason is:

> Although z-index is not a difficult property to understand, due to
>   false assumptions it can cause confusion for beginning developers.
>   This confusion occurs because z-index will only work on an element
>   whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or
>   relative.

As explained at the site below:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Also, you mispelled "Perfect" on your site. :D